# How do I create an in-app update for a mobile game?

Tags: android, ios, patching

I'm researching how to make an in app update on mobile game.

When there is a hotfix, or an update, I don't want users to have to go to Play store, or App Store to update, but rather for them to update inside the game (like in Clash of Clans). I want to do this because Apple takes too much time for reviewing.

I found https://ionic.io, they use Cordova to embebed HTML inside. We can do live update, rollback to old version with a click. This is pretty suitable for normal app, but for game, the performance is not great.

How can I create an in-app update like this?

Answer (score 3):

As Ophir Prusak points out, Apple does not allow downloading code to your app.

So one possibility is that you could make your game logic and behavior entirely data-driven. Then all you do is download new data to the app, and your game changes.

This is not a simple solution, however.

Answer (score -1):

For iOS, you're not allowed to remotely inject native obj-c code, but you can either inject JavaScript, or use any existing code already in the app.

Your best bet is to use method swizzling in order to actually change the behavior of the app:
http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

You should also check out Google Tag Manager for mobile which is an awesome tool to directly push new configuration data to apps:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xe8W5w68BRg

I only know of one solution that provides code level updates for Obj-C apps remotely - https://rollout.io

Check out the video that shows how it works:
http://support.rollout.io/docs/video-fix-a-bug-with-rolloutio

and here is some more info on reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/3rjdfo/experiences_with_rolloutio/

(fyi, I work at Rollout)